# A table can not be created with the name Service in mixed case against innoDB of mysql 5.1.69

Tags: mysql, innodb

The following create table (Against the default MyISAM) executes correctly and creates the table:

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Service`;
CREATE TABLE `Service` (
`idService` INT,
PRIMARY KEY (`idService`)
);

however when created in the builtin innodb of mysql 5.1.69 it fails.

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Service`;
CREATE TABLE `Service` (
`idService` INT,
PRIMARY KEY (`idService`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

```
Error: Can't create table 'myDatabase.Service' (errno: -1)(1005)
```

The builtin innodb is a different code base to the plugin but much of 5.1.69 appears to be similar to the plugin of 1.0.3 -- it was the builtin innodb being used.

If the table is named Zervice on the same server it works correctly against InnoDB.

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Zervice`;
CREATE TABLE `Zervice` (
`idService` INT,
PRIMARY KEY (`idService`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

Even more strangely if the table is named in upper case as SERVICE it is created.

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `SERVICE`;
CREATE TABLE `SERVICE` (
`idService` INT,
PRIMARY KEY (`idService`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

I'm however creating many other tables with other names in mixed case without any problem. Both I manually and mysql workbench are failing to create the table Service against innoDB.

Also on another server running 5.0 the table can be created as Service in innoDB and has been running as such for some time (In the tests above I am using a cut down table which I have executed and tested with).

The word Service is not listed on mysql's keywords pages (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/reserved-words.html) however the problem appears to be innoDB specific and there is not a separate list of innoDB keywords if there are any intended. Notice also that the left leaning quotes are being used around the table name.

select table_name from information_schema.TABLES where upper(table_name) = 'SERVICE';
Returns no rows.

Can anybody shed any light on why the word Service may be significant to innoDB from 5.1 or why case is significant in this situation (All servers are Ubuntu)?

Answer (score 1):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-error-codes.html

> 1005 (ER_CANT_CREATE_TABLE)
>
> Cannot create table. If the error message refers to error 150, table creation failed because a foreign key constraint was not correctly formed. If the error message refers to error –1, table creation probably failed because the table includes a column name that matched the name of an internal InnoDB table.

So it's not an SQL reserved word, but it apparently conflicts with something in InnoDB.

PS: I strongly recommend you just use the InnoDB plugin and never use the InnoDB builtin if you're on MySQL 5.1.69.  See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replacing-builtin-innodb.html

---

Update:  I tried this myself on a MySQL Sandbox installation of MySQL Community edition 5.1.70, and I can't reproduce any problem.  That is, I can create both the table `Service` or `SERVICE` with no errors.

```
select table_name from information_schema.TABLES where upper(table_name) = 'SERVICE';
+------------+
| table_name |
+------------+
| SERVICE    |
| Service    |
+------------+

show create table Service\G

CREATE TABLE `Service` (
  `idService` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`idService`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Once in a while I find that InnoDB's data dictionary gets confused.  Either through corruption, or else doing something inadvisable like removing an InnoDB table outside MySQL with `rm` instead of using `DROP TABLE`.  So the internal data dictionary may think that you still have a table named `Service` even though you don't have one physically on disk, and the information_schema doesn't report one.

If that's the case, you might not be able to correct the situation without some drastic steps, like:

1. Convert all InnoDB tables to MyISAM temporarily.
2. Shut down mysqld.
3. Remove `ibdata1` (this is where InnoDB stores its data dictionary).
4. Start up mysqld.
5. Reconvert all your tables back to InnoDB.

I can't guarantee this is the root cause of the error, but those steps would rebuild the data dictionary.

Comment: Well after a further several days of dropping, rebuilding etc. I still have the same problem. As you say the error indicates no more than that it "conflicts with something in innoDB". I don't control the infrastructure versions used so I'm giving in and using a different table name.

Answer (score 0):

You can create table named `Service`. I checked with MySQL 5.5.32

The following works for me

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Service`; CREATE TABLE `Service` ( idService INT, PRIMARY KEY (idService) );
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Service; CREATE TABLE Service ( idService INT, PRIMARY KEY (idService) ) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

When I execute the above 2 commands I get 2 tables `Service` and `SERVICE`. May be it is a bug in `mysql 5.1.69` (don't know). Try to upgrade MySQL if possible.

Table details below.

```
Name       Engine    Rows    Data Size   Index Size    Total Size
-----------------------------------------------------------------
SERVICE    InnoDB     0        16K           0            16K
Service    InnoDB     0        16K           0            16K
```

The output of `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%version%'`

```
Variable_name              Value
---------------------------------
innodb_version             5.5.32
protocol_version           10
slave_type_conversions
version                    5.5.32
version_comment            MySQL Community Server (GPL)
version_compile_machine    x86_64
version_compile_os         Linux
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to reproduce. You don't specify the engine in your query. It works against MyISAM but not against innoDB. The 'ENGINE=InnoDB;' on the end of the query is significant as most servers default to MyISAM maybe you know yours defaults to InnoDB but it would still be reassuring. It's also likely the issue is mysql version specific in that it seems to have come in between 5.0 and 5.1. If it's good in 5.5 with the built in innoDB that still gives hope.

Comment: I have my default engine set to `InnoDB` and am using the built in `InnoDB`  I have updated the answer with details.